# android File.createTempFile() fails with Environment.getExternalStorageDirector()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to write an app which takes a photo and save it into the gallery.

I've followed the Android Developers' guide, but it only shows how to same images into a private directory.

Here is the code I use to send the intent to the camera

```
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                2121);

        return;

    }

    //File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = null;
    try {
        image= File.createTempFile("IMG", ".jpg", storageDir);
        //tempImage=image;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("error", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        return;
    }

    //photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "prova.fileprovider", image);

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null ) {
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}
```

When I run it on the Android Studio emulator (Pixel_API_27) I get the error when calling the File.createTempFile

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Which error do you get? I why do you continue with your code if there is a catch? Add a return statement.

Comment: How do I get the error? The app simply shuts down.

Comment: No. The logcat  will tell  which exceptions you did not catch. Post the relevant parts from the logcat.

Comment: FileUriExposedException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution by working around the problem.
I make the camera intent to save the picture to the private app folder,
then I move the file to the public one. Here is the code

```
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {

    //ask write permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                2121);

        return;

    }

    //get path to private folder
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    //create temp-file where the image will be saved
    File image = null;
    try {
        image= File.createTempFile("IMG", ".jpg", storageDir);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("error", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        return;
    }


    Image = image;

    //get uri of the image
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "prova.fileprovider", image);

    //send the intent to the camera
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null ) {
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

}
```

Then when the picture is take I do

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { //AFTER TAKING PICTURE

        File publicImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + Image.getName());
        Image.renameTo(publicImage); //here we move the file to the public directory
        Image = publicImage;

        //optionally one can update the gallery, but I don't need it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android 6+ you have to add code to ask the user to confirm the read write permissions you requested in manifest.

Google for runtime permissions.

You are #1246 this year who is posting this problem.

Comment: I changed the code as you can see above. Now when the app is run for the first time it asks for permissions. However, when I call the function again, the application shuts down. So there is still a problem.